# Monogame performance update logic very bad, why?

Tags: c#, performance, draw, monogame

Programs and versions i'm running:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2012 Professional
- Monogame 3.2
- OpenGL project

Problem: When i update my game in below loop, i open task manager and see that the program is taking up 25 CPU! this is way too much.

The loop:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();
        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        if (angleCounter != 359)
            angleCounter++;
        else
            angleCounter = 0;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

The loop makes an angle (degrees) increment so that the image (png) i'm drawing is spinning constantly

The drawing part:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        Vector2 location = new Vector2(200, 200);
        Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, sprite.Width, sprite.Height);
        Vector2 origin = new Vector2(sprite.Width / 2, sprite.Height / 2);

        float angle = (float)DegreeToRadianal(angleCounter);

        spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, location, sourceRectangle, Color.White, angle, origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

EDIT: I have ran a profiler, this is what it says: 
[image]

**Also: My computer itself is not the problem, it is a very high end PC that should be able to run a program like this with 01 CPU**

Comment: Have you run this through any kind of .NET profiler to see where the performance drain is?  We can't do that step for you.

Comment: Let me guess: you have a CPU with 4 cores.....

Comment: Yeah, quad core i5 4670k haswell. other programs are no problem at all, even crysis 3 and battlefield 3 at max settings no problems whatsoever :|

Comment: What is your update rate set to?

Comment: "...should be able to run a program like this with 01 CPU" First, there are not 25 CPU and 01 CPU "units". Assuming you are talking about % utilization, then it is probably your code or your choice of API or other technology.

Comment: I don't know, monogame takes care of that part for me, i'm very new to monogame.. but since the animation looks good, nice and smooth, i think around 16ms (60FPS).

Comment: You should try to limit your framerate. I don't know about monogame, but this is a common problem when running such loops. Try googling something like "gameloop 100% cpu". You're not the first and not the last one with that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. What's the basis for your performance metric?

A universal factor in designing for performance is that you need a business-centric definition of "fast enough" to aim for. Does your user care if your game uses 25% of their CPU? No. Your user cares whether or not your game runs smoothly. Does your game run smoothly?

> "the animation looks good, nice and smooth"

Looks like your program runs fast enough!

[Don't waste time fixing things that aren't broken](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

### 2. It looks like your game loop is rate-unlimited.

That means your program basically says to your computer "Run this loop as fast as you possibly can!"

Given that, how do you arrive at your conclusion that your computer "should be able to run a program like this" with 1% CPU utilisation?

It seems quite self-evident that a rate-unlimited loop will cause 100% CPU utilisation irrespective of clock speed (=25% on a 4-core machine like yours)!

If for some reason it's very very important to you that the game not run as fast as possible, you could try setting:-

```
IsFixedTimeStep = true;
```

in your game constructor, but make sure you clearly understand the implications of a fixed vs a variable time step:-

- http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/time-steps
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step

Comment: Thank you for your advice! to react: 1: this is just one animation, a very tiny one, and you and I both know it shouldn't take 25% (or 1 full core). That is just a flaw that can be fixed. 2: Thx! I know understand why it's 25% instead of 100%, also my base.update() calls the method it is in, so it is recursively, though.. when I check how many times the method is being called it says 60 times per second.. I also tried the IsFixedTimeStep and it didn't work.. sorry

Comment: It isn't a flaw. You don't lose anything by utilising the CPU. You don't gain anything by underutilising it. If you're worried about how this will affect your performance when your scene becomes more complicated, then why don't you set up a realistic test of your more complicated scene and then profile that?

Comment: Interesting about still having 100% CPU utilisation even with fixed time steps. You could take a look at the source code here:- https://github.com/mono/MonoGame and find out what's going on in-between steps. I can't see the screenshot of your profiler session here, though, so I can't help dig deeper, sorry.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand this whole thing, see, i'm a normal programmer, and not a game programmer. I'm used to very low CPU requiring programs and websites, I didn't realise that games use 100% of CPU anyway or is this wrong too? I mean, i started an empty Monogame OpenGL project, written nothing of code in it, and it still took 25% CPU, is that just the way that games run?

Comment: @KamikazeChicken: most games run with a loop at their core - the "game loop" is responsible for updating the world and then drawing a frame to the screen (more or less, depending on engine/implementation). That loop will typically run *as fast as possible* as any artificial delay would just be a performance hit (that is: reduction in framerate!) for the game. So yes, even an empty scene will typically run to a full CPU - because it'll be drawing as many empty frames as it possibly can.

Comment: Seriously, you guys are amazing, thank you all! How is it that you guys can answer these hard questions so damn quickly?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Based on you guys' great help and research on Google, I have found the following:

- Monogame intends for the program to run as fast as it can, instead of "saving" the computers' CPU. therefore it "reserves" 1 core (more cores when you get a really really high demand).
- The difference between a normal program and a game is huge, normal programs intent to minimize the CPU, therefore the impact on the computer, games intent to make the game itself run smoother by making the computer work harder
- Last: I should make clear what my intentions are, for example: I didn't state in this particular question that I wanted to make an as low impact CPU game while still keeping a smooth game (60fps)

Thank you all for helping me come to these conclusions by answering so quickly!